# Have replacement anatomical parts with silver electroplating hit the market and do they eliminate infection concerns?

Tags: infection

According to [this study from 2005 of the viability of silver plated replacement anatomical devices](https://aac.asm.org/content/60/4/2467) there appeared to be great promise. Has this promise come true? Are they available now and are they the proverbial "silver bullet" for eliminating infection of replacement anatomical parts?

Comment: Prior research. A quick google search showed there is research in this area, so providing some background should be easy.